# How to apply policy to offline device

Tags: android-management-api

I am using Android management API. I have applied policy to device and turned it to kiosk mode. After a while when I turn on the device, it is not connected to wifi anymore and is still in kiosk mode. Therefore I cannot connect it manually or update its policy. Is there a way to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you cannot open the wifi dialog and devices cannot update the policy without a connection, the only way to workaround this is to hard reset the device per OEM instruction.

In the future, you can use [KioskCustomization](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#kioskcustomization) to have access to the status bar and navigation buttons so there would be no need to hard reset the device again if there is no connection as you can open the wifi dialog with this.

Answer (score 0):

For people wondering how to escape the kiosk mode. There should be a way for your device to reboot to recovery mode. I my case - samsung tablet - I hold power button and volume down button for a while and when samsung logo appeared a released the power button, but still hold the volume down button. In recovery mode I were able to connect to wifi manually.